# page content in multiple languages

Tags: asp.net, localization

I want to display content in more than one languages in a page. For example all menus are in English and content of post in local language (ie. Hindi).

Contents on page are stored in database. For one post content can be in either language (only one language not all) not in both.

Comment: Ok. If that is what you want...

Comment: There's no question here. What do you want to know?

Comment: Just make your menu's a different partial page and now you can set language on either page differently.

Comment: if it has done and no issue you should mark as answer and up vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I want to display a page in only one language(ie. one page is in Hindi another is in English).So there will exactly one version of a page.

I achieved this by changing data type of field from text to ntext.